# How to resolve java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError with Macbook Pro M1 with Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, apple-m1

I am using Macbook Pro M1 chipset machine and using Java 8(openjdk version "1.8.0_333") and when I am trying to run netty based service, getting below error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no io_grpc_netty_shaded_netty_tcnative_osx_aarch_64 in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1860)
```

My colleague is using Intel based Macbook Pro and he is not getting this error.

Can anybody know how to resolve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you getting netty? There needs to be an arm version if they have any native libs.

Comment: through maven. I am trying to resolve by this tag but not able to:
`<dependency>
<groupId>io.netty</groupId>
<artifactId>netty-transport-native-epoll</artifactId>
<classifier>osx-aarch_64</classifier>
<version>4.1.63.Final</version>
</dependency>`

Comment: Okay, and that builds and downloads the libs ok? How are you starting your app with netty, it seems like you should have the correct native libs, and your application doesn't find them when you run it.

Comment: the thing is even if I create new maven project and add `kqueue` dependency it will be there but when I am trying for `epoll` it fails to download it, please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72847122/missing-osx-aarch-64-classifier-version-for-netty-transport-native-epoll