# Missing osx-aarch_64 classifier version for netty-transport-native-epoll

Tags: java, macos, java-8, netty, apple-m1

I am working on one project where I need 'netty-transport-native-epoll' library.
I am using Apple M1 Macbook Pro and I am not able to download it for osx-aarch_64 classifier.
However I am able to download this Jar:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>io.netty</groupId>
<artifactId>netty-transport-native-kqueue</artifactId>
<classifier>osx-aarch_64</classifier>
<version>4.1.63.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

but I am NOT able to resolve below dependency:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>io.netty</groupId>
<artifactId>netty-transport-native-epoll</artifactId>
<classifier>osx-aarch_64</classifier>
<version>4.1.63.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Can somebody please guide as How to resolve this on M1 Macbook.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If you check https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/netty/netty-transport-native-epoll/4.1.63.Final/ they don't appear to have an osx-aarch_64. There is a linux one.

Comment: Yes, I need osx-aarch_64 for M1 macbook. How to resolve this?

Comment: It sounds like you'll have to build the libs if possible. Did you check their project page? It sounds like they want you to use the KQueue version. https://netty.io/wiki/native-transports.html

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with netty, but https://github.com/netty/netty/issues there are some m1 issues. (some closed). If you really think that you should be able to use the epoll with an M1 create an issue and maybe somebody will tell you how to compile it.

Comment: sure. thank you. will raise it on github.

Answer (score 0):

`epoll` is not available for MacOS because it's based on FreeBSD (but `kqueue` available), so even if you will able to download dependency it won't work. What you can do is to check dynamically for `epoll` using Netty's `Epoll.isAvailable()` and fallback to NIO or run your application in docker container with ubuntu (or other distr which support `epoll`). Docker will use VM under the hood and `epoll` would be available.